# How to change legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I do the exercice with iris data set. I almost do what I want, but the the legend appear twice .

Is it possible to "translate" the legend ?
If I try with : scale_color_discrete see the result below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdark)
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width )) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
  xlab("Longueur des sépales") + 
  ylab("Largeur des sépales") +
  ggtitle("Largeur et longueur des sépales") +
    scale_color_discrete(name = "Espèces") +
    dark_theme_gray() +
   theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Roboto"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey10"),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey30", size = 0.2),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey30", size = 0.5),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.815, 0.85))
```

And the result:

[image: Result iris_1]

And if I try with label:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdark)
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width )) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species)) +
  labs(title = "Largeurs et longueurs des sépales par espèce",
        caption = "Jeu de donnée iris",
         x = "Longueur des sépales",
         y = "Largeur des sépales",
         colour = "Espèces"
     ) +
   theme(
     plot.title = element_text(family = "Roboto"),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "grey10"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "grey30", size = 0.2),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = "grey30", size = 0.5),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank() 
     ) +
    dark_theme_gray()
```

[image: Result iris_2]

There is something that I don't understand.
Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

Adding `scale_shape_discrete(name = "Espèces")` will do.

```
ggplot(data=iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,color=Species, shape=Species )) +
  geom_point(aes()) +
  xlab("Longueur des sépales") + 
  ylab("Largeur des sépales") +
  ggtitle("Largeur et longueur des sépales") +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "Espèces") +
  scale_shape_discrete(name = "Espèces") +
  dark_theme_gray()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Park. I will continue to practice and try to understand the grammar. I saw , that you put colour and shape in the ggplot aes, and not in the geom_point aes .

Comment: @ordinatous It doesn't matter where `colour/color` or `shape` locate either in `ggplot(...)` or `geom_point(...)`.  But I specify those in `ggplot(...)`, I do not need to specify any more for those code. But when you want to set different `color` or `shape` or `fill` for different type of graphics(`geom_point`, `geom_col/bar` or etc), in this case, you'd better specify `color` sort of things separately. As I understand in your question, your problem is that different two legends for `color` and `shape`, you can combine them with add both `scale_color_discrete` and `scale_shape_discrete`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand.Help really appriciate .